# remove the duplicate rows in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have the following python function that exports JSON data to CSV file, it works fine - the keys(csv headers) and values(csv rows) are populated in the CSV, but I'm trying to remove the duplicates rows in the the csv file?

instead of manually removing them in Excel, how do I remove the duplicate values in python?

```
 def toCSV(res):
        with open('EnrichedEvents.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['process_hash', 'process_name', "process_effective_reputation"]
            dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,extrasaction='ignore')
            dict_writer.writeheader()
            for r in res:
                dict_writer.writerow(r)
```

Thank you

for example in the csv, the duplicate row on apmsgfwd.exe information.

duplicate data below:

```
process_hash    process_name    process_effective_reputation
['f810a809e9cdf70c3189008e07c83619', '58d44528b60d36b515359fe234c9332ccef6937f5c950472230ce15dca8812e2']    c:\windows\system32\delltpad\apmsgfwd.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
['73ca11f2acf1adb7802c2914e1026db899a3c851cd9500378c0045e0']    c:\users\zdr3dds01\documents\sap\sap gui\export.mhtml   NOT_LISTED
['f810a809e9cdf70c3189008e07c83619', '58d44528b60d36b515359fe234c9332ccef6937f5c950472230ce15dca8812e2']    c:\windows\system32\delltpad\apmsgfwd.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
['f810a809e9cdf70c3189008e07c83619', '58d44528b60d36b515359fe234c9332ccef6937f5c950472230ce15dca8812e2']    c:\windows\system32\delltpad\apmsgfwd.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
['582f018bc7a732d63f624d6f92b3d143', '66505bcb9975d61af14dd09cddd9ac0d11a3e2b5ae41845c65117e7e2b046d37']    c:\users\jij09\appdata\local\kingsoft\power word 2016\2016.3.3.0368\powerword.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
```

json data:

```
[{'device_name': 'fk6sdc2', 'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z', 'event_id': '9b1bvf6e17ee11eb81b', 'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST', 'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935830f3a9df8e9b6425c37a', 'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'], 'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\toh122soft\\thcasdf3\\toho34rce.exe', 'process_username': ['JOHN\\user1']}, {'device_name': 'fk6sdc2', 'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z', 'event_id': '9b151f6e17ee11eb81b', 'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST', 'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935f3a9df8e9b6830425c37a', 'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'], 'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\oft\\tf3\\tootsice.exe', 'process_username': ['JOHN\\user2']}, {'device_name': '6asdsdc2', 'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z', 'event_id': '9b151f698e11eb81b', 'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST', 'process_hash': ['9df8ebfc7dcf5935830f3a9b6425c37a', 'ca9f3a24506cc518ff6ddc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f7124641ad1734e2f19'], 'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\toht\\th3\\tohce.exe', 'process_username': ['JOHN\\user3']}]
```

Comment: share an example of the csv and define 'duplicate'

Comment: thanks balderman, i've added a screenshot of the csv file,

Comment: please do no upload images - add the csv (or a subset of it) as text.

Comment: Why you shouldn't upload images of text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/843953

Comment: sorry about that, i've added csv data in text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate rows from a csv file using a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741564/removing-duplicate-rows-from-a-csv-file-using-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is standalone example that shows how to filter duplicates. The idea is to get the values of each dict and convert them into tuple. Using a set we can filter out the duplicates.

```
import csv

csv_columns = ['No', 'Name', 'Country']
dict_data = [
    {'No': 1, 'Name': 'Alex', 'Country': ['India']},
    {'No': 1, 'Name': 'Alex', 'Country': ['India']},
    {'No': 1, 'Name': 'Alex', 'Country': ['India']},
    {'No': 1, 'Name': 'Alex', 'Country': ['India']},
    {'No': 2, 'Name': 'Ben', 'Country': ['USA']},

]
csv_file = "Names.csv"

with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    entries = set()
    for data in dict_data:
        val = tuple(','.join(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for v in data.values())
        if val not in entries:
            writer.writerow(data)
            entries.add(val)
print('done')
```

Names.csv

```
 No,Name,Country
1,Alex,['India']
2,Ben,['USA']
```

Comment: thanks balderman, sorry i should have mentioned earlier, how do use your approach if the 'res' variable holds list of dicts(json data)

Comment: @user3704597 did you try it?

Comment: hi balderman, i get the following error:         if r not in r_set:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: thanks for helping me out balderman, i tried the new code above. but now I'm getting the error below(i think its because there are values with  list type - for example india is in [india])     if val not in entries:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user3704597 code was updated and it takes care of lists as well

Comment: @PranavHosangadi OK - explanations added.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to use above approach, if not then I usually use pandas library for reading csv files.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('EnrichedEvents.csv')
data.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

data.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```