# Python: How to close my CSV input and output files?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.5, linux-mint

Hi I have been experimenting with **Winston Ewert's** code example from this thread.

[Python: Removing duplicate CSV entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682796/python-removing-duplicate-csv-entries?newreg=eb76df667d7a4636a29df8a2cfae8fcc)

But I can't close my input and output files.  What am I doing wrong?

**write_outfile.close()**

**write_infile.close()**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "Duplicates_01.py", line 26, in  write_outfile.close() AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close'

```
import csv

write_infile = csv.reader(open('File1.csv', 'r'))
write_outfile = csv.writer(open('File2.csv', 'w'))

#write_infile = open('File1.csv', 'r')
#f1 = csv.reader(write_infile)
#f1 = csv.reader(write_infile, delimiter=' ')

#write_outfile = open('File2.csv', 'w')
#f2 = csv.writer(write_outfile)
#f2 = csv.writer(write_outfile, delimiter=' ')

phone_numbers = set()

for row in write_infile:
    if row[1] not in phone_numbers:
        write_outfile.writerow(row)
#       f2.writerow(row)
        phone_numbers.add(row[1])

# write_outfile.close()
# write_infile.close()
```

File1.csv

```
user, phone, email
joe, 123, joe@x.com
mary, 456, mary@x.com
ed, 123, ed@x.com
```

Comment: Why can't you close them? What error are you getting? Why have you commented out the close statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by doing:

```
csv.reader(open('File1.csv', 'r'))
```

you're passing an anonymous file handle to `csv.reader` objects, so you cannot control when the file will be closed (it's this handle which needs to be closed, not the `csv.reader` object)

The `close` method must apply to the file handle (csv reader/writer objects can work on lists, iterators, ..., they can't have a `close` method) so I would do:

```
fr = open('File1.csv', 'r')
```

and

```
csv.reader(fr)
```

then

```
fr.close()
```

or use a context manager:

```
with open('File1.csv', 'r') as fr:
    csv.reader(fr)
```

and file will be closed as soon as you leave the context

Aside: there's an extra catch when creating csv files on some python versions. using a handle like `open('File2.csv', 'w')` may cause problems (blank lines inserted). For a compatible & robust way you can read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808284/portable-way-to-write-csv-file-in-python-2-or-python-3)